Showing that $\sum_{a\in A} 4^{-a}\neq \sum_{b\in B}4^{-b}$ where $A\neq B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$

Let $A,B\in P(\mathbb{N})$ with $A\neq B$. Note that $A, B$ can be finite or infinite. Show that
$$
\sum_{a\in A} 4^{-a}\neq \sum_{b\in B}4^{-b}
$$

So I'm not entirely sure this claim is true, but I think it is (or might be true with some modification). I think I know how to prove it assuming that $A, B$ has a finite number of different elements using induction. However, in the more general case, I'm stuck. The bigger problem I'm facing is to show that
$$
f:P(\mathbb{N})\to\mathbb{R}\\
A\mapsto\sum_{a\in A}4^{-a}
$$
is injective, so solutions that tackle this directly are welcome.

Hints: First, try to prove that if $s$ is the smallest element in a set $S \subset \mathbb{N}$, then $$4^{-s} \le \sum_{n \in S}4^{-n} \le \dfrac{4}{3} \cdot 4^{-s}.$$
Next, check that $$f(A) - f(B) = \sum_{n \in A}4^{-n} - \sum_{n \in B}4^{-n} = \sum_{n \in A\setminus B}4^{-n} - \sum_{n \in B\setminus A}4^{-n}.$$
After you do this, let $a$ be the smallest element in $A \setminus B$ and $b$ be the smallest element in $B \setminus A$. Note that $a \neq b$. See if you can use that first result to bound $f(A)-f(B) > 0$ when $a < b$ and $f(A)-f(B) < 0$ when $a > b$.

Assume $A\neq B$. Let $n$ be the first number that appears in exactly one of $A$ and $B$. Then $B\cap\{1,\cdots,n-1\}=A\cap\{1,\cdots,n-1\}$.
WLOG, assume $n\in A$. Note that
$$\sum_{b\in B}4^{-b}\leq \sum_{b\in B,b<n}4^{-b}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}4^{-k}=\sum_{a\in A,a<n}4^{-a}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}4^{-k}<\sum_{a\in A,a<n}4^{-a}+4^{-n}\leq \sum_{a\in A}4^{-a}$$
which is a contradiction!
